# Localization of javax.swing.JOptionPane's default button labels in OS X

Tags: java, macos, localization, joptionpane

How can this be achieved?  I have the ff. test code:

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello, world!");
```

Running it with, say, `-Duser.language=zh` and `-Duser.country=TW` doesn't work.  I.e., the OK button is still labeled "OK".  In Windows, for example, it is replaced with the Traditional Chinese equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prioritize the corresponding language in System Preferences > International.

Aqua is used if the LAF isn't specified.  It doesn't respect the default locale probably because it's very much integrated into the OS.

If a cross-platform LAF is used (e.g., Metal), the problem is not observed.